# Connecting Flask To AWS RDS using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I have been trying to connect my aws RDS database instance to a flask application I have downloaded. I have been following  https://medium.com/@rodkey/deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-a72daba6bb80 and using the flask app on this github to connect to the database https://github.com/inkjet/flask-aws-tutorial. I have set the permissions on my RDS server correctly and have been using the following code to connect to the DB.

```
# edit the URI below to add your RDS password and your AWS URL
# The other elements are the same as used in the tutorial
# format: (user):(password)@(db_identifier).amazonaws.com:3306/(db_name)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://{userName}:{password}@{endpoint}:3306/{dbName}'

# Uncomment the line below if you want to work with a local DB
#SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///test.db'

SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 3600

WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
```

I am still receiving a timeout error:

```
    {path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:834: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 583, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 728, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2345, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '{endpoint}' (timed out)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_create.py", line 4, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1039, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1031, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4465, in create_all
    ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2103, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2095, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self._contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2311, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2349, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1591, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2345, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "{path_to_virt_env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '{endpoint}' (timed out)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8
```

If any more information is needed, please let me know!

Comment: You are connecting from where? From inside AWS or outside?

Comment: I am connecting from outside AWS, from my personal computer. Using a virtual environment. However, I have set the database such that all incoming and outgoing ip addresses are allowed.

Comment: Is the RDS set to allow public access? But default its not.

Comment: That worked! I turned on public access and was able to access the DB. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. I will make an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, the issue was that RDS's  **public accessibility** setting was not enabled.

The solution was to enable it.